# Prevent iOS HTML5 app from refreshing webpage when video exits full screen mode

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, video

I have an HTML5/JS app that dynamically loads a series of videos into a custom lightbox, but when I exit one of the videos after viewing it in full screen the entire app page refreshes.

How do I prevent the page refresh from occurring?

Note: This only happens on an iPad 2+ running iOS6.0.1. It doesn't happen on an iPad 1 running 5.1.1.